# Command line for 7z to extract specific files from specific folders inside an archive

Tags: python, archive, 7zip

I'm writing a Python script where I need to call 7z to extract some files kept inside a directory in an archive without extracting the complete archive. The archive contains multiple directories and I need to extract some files from a particular directory.

Let's say, "abc.7z" is an archive which contains multiple directories, i.e  "temp", "windows", "system", "data". I want to extract some .exe files from directory "system" only because those .exe files might be present in other directories too but I am interested only in the files from "system".

All I need is the 7z command; I'll figure out how to call 7z from the script. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can specify a file/folder filter at the end of the command line. Check [this](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm) for more details on 7zip command line commands and options.

```
7z.exe x [archive.7z] -o[output_dir] [filter]
```

e.g. `7z.exe x abc.7z -aoa -oC:\Temp system`

You can also specify files of a particular type from system folder. For e.g. `system\*.exe` will extract all `.exe` files inside the `system` directory.

`-aoa` option is for overwrite mode.

To call it from Python you can use `subprocess` module. Something like:

```
import subprocess

cmd = []
cmd.append(r'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe')
cmd.append('x')
cmd.append(archive)
cmd.append('-aoa')
cmd.append('-o{}'.format(dst_part))
cmd.append(file_folder_filter)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: So it means that `7z.exe x abc.7z -aoa -oC:\Temp system\*.exe` will be the final command to extract only the .exe file from the system folder.

Comment: On my side, i need to add '.' before to make it works. That is to extract 'system' directory only i need to pass './system'

Comment: Note: you can use `e` instead of `x` if you want to get the files without the path they had inside the zip

Comment: Note for bash users regarding wildcards: use apostroph to not have bash trying to expand the wildcards. Like `7z e abc.7z "system/*.exe"`

Answer (score 5):

Steps to extract a specific directory from 7z zip:

Specific Directory: `rootdir/firstson/second`

Zip file : test.7z

Command to use :

```
7z x test.7z rootdir/firstson/second
```

Comment: Actually i need to pass './rootdir/firstson/second' to make it work